# Microsoft Translator: Has anyone been able to translate TextBoxes within a Docx?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, docx

Microsoft Document Translator works very well for all Docx's I've tried.  However, any Docx (Word Document) that contains a TextBox fails to translate, or even recognize its existence (doesn't even keep the box un-translated).
If anyone has advice on handling this, it would be greatly appreciated!
Regards
Rusty

I have used the translator on many different documents of varying sizes and none of them translated or even replicated the original.
It actually eliminates the TextBox and contents from the translation.

This is true for the Microsoft online translation functions as well as through their API.